# AJAX form submitting in HTML rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked through several of these kind of questions but none of them work for me.

Weirdly enough the same strategy to a different form works perfectly.

I have model validations in place but when I submit an empty form I get an error of missing template of ceeate where format is HTML.

I guess the purpose of each file is self-explanatory.

My ContactsController.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js
     def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
  end
end
```

new.js.ebr:

```
$("#main-block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'contact_form') %>")
```

_contact_form.html.erb:

```
<div align="center">
  <h3>Sazinieties ar mums</h3>
  <ul class="errors"></ul>

  <%= form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: "control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="control-group"><div class="field">
        <%= f.label :e_mail, class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.email_field :e_mail %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group"><div class="field">
        <%= f.label :message, class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_area :message %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
            <%= f.submit('Sūtīt', remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary")  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

create.js. erb:

```
<%= render 'save' %>
```

_save.js.erb:

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @contact.errors.any? %>
  <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  $("#main-block").empty()
  $("#main-block").html("Ziņa ir nosūtīta. Tuvākajā laikā sniegsim atbildi!")
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to your form:

```
<%= form_for @contact, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

And remove remote: true from your submit button.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to that you use remote true with forms like that.